What should I consider when determining what `ALLOC_MAX` should be in this type of I/O loop?
For, e.g. determining an amount of memory that is safe to allocate for processing file or device with this type of I/O loop:
 HANDLE hFile /* = file open with GENERIC_READ */;
 LARGE_INTEGER liSize;
 SIZE_T cbAlloc;
 BYTE *pBuffer = NULL;

 GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &liSize);
 while(liSize.QuadPart)
 {
     cbAlloc = min(ALLOC_MAX, liSize.QuadPart);
     /* Allocate pBuffer with cbAlloc bytes size, 
        Use pBuffer, then Free pBuffer... */
     liSize.QuadPart -= cbAlloc;
 }

Right now my ALLOC_MAX is a macro constant.
However, when researching a way to determine a safe amount to allocate dynamically, with e.g. GlobalMemoryStatusEx, my next question is, how does even this information (including total physical memory available) even help me determine what the right amount is for ALLOC_MAX? It would not be wise to allocate the exact amount of available memory, would it? What is a reasonable amount to try to allocate, three-quarters of the available amount? Half of it?

Why would you do such a huge allocation? On the contrary, you should try to allocate something small, around the size of page, maybe more, say 10kb, and stream the data.

You should consider

which kind of target system(s) you are aiming for, and how much real memory they will have at minimum

what other kind of programs and processes will run at the same machine at the same time, or if your program is running on a box which is dedicated for your process exclusively

what you are hoping to gain from allocating 1GB at a whole - will there be any significant performance difference when you choose a much smaller buffer, lets say 1k, 10k, maybe 100k? (And don't guess - measure!)

why ALLOC_MAX is a constant. Depending on the context, this choice might be fine, but maybe you want the memory consumption of the program configurable, for example, to adapt it to the specific machine or environment where the process will be executed.


The ideal choice for ALLOC_MAX is the smallest one which gives you acceptable performance - if you make it configurable, it will be  easier to make some benchmarks in different environments without any need to recompile the program.

“Measure” is bold for a reason.

lets say 1k, 10k, maybe 100k? IME page-sized multiples will probably perform best, so 8kb, 128kb, etc.  Also IME, unless the IO system is specifically designed for high-performance IO and the code is properly "tuned" to match things like file system block sizes and just about every other detail of the storage system, single-threaded read/writes with a buffer that's just a handful of pages gets about 95% or better of the performance from huge buffers such as 1 GB.  IMO it wouldn't be unreasonable to just hardcode a 16 KB buffer size and forget about it.

@AndrewHenle: all correct, but what we don't know is what the OP's code is actually doing with the buffer content, in the sections they did not show us, which can have a significant influence on choosing the size.

@AndrewHenle Have you measured it?

@gnasher729 For decades.  On many different operating systems and storage devices.  And often ending up writing up detailed performance analysis of systems with lots of graphs and pretty colors for management types.  If you're not running on a system designed from the ground up for high-speed IO performance and your code isn't tuned to match the characteristics of the storage controller(s) and actual layout of data on disk, just doing simple, sequential reads or writes using a 8 or 16 kb buffer will go almost as fast as complex muliple-buffer/multiple-thread schemes or huge buffers do

You measured it for decades. You. Personally you. You come up with all kinds of platitudes but I bet you havent measured anything. My Mac can copy a 4K buffer in memory in 40 nanoseconds. So what did you measure?

Spinning hard drives have had track caches for years. So actual data layout on the disk is totally irrelevant. Even more so for an SSD drive. The storage controller is quite irrelevant when my Mac has usually a few gigabytes of cached files. And WTF is talking about “complex multiple buffet multiple thread schemes” and huge buffers? I was talking about age old prejudices about powers of two. Doc Brown was talking about “1k, 10k, 100k” and he didn’t write “kibi” so he meant thousands.

@gnasher729 Spinning hard drives have had track caches for years  I'll let you do the math on how long it takes for a 12 gbps SAS link to overwhelm even a 256 MB disk cache. (Hint: not long at all...) he didn’t write “kibi” so he meant thousands  "kibi"?!?!?  Oh please.  Read this Seagate spec sheet  The very source of corporate-lying-about-capacity-bribe-the-ISO "kibi" bogus units uses MB to mean a power-of-two value.  So no, it's not clear at all.

@gnasher729: I think for explaning my point it makes no difference whether I wrote "k" or "kb" - to be honest, today I have no idea whether this was intentional or a typo at the time when I was writing it ;-)

You measure. You hope that one 1GB read is faster than 1000 1MB reads. You are missing that you are using memory that might be needed elsewhere (so another app on your computer starts swapping), and your data doesn’t fit into L2 cache anymore, which can make a massive difference. So there are plenty reasons why a big size might be slower.

Re: "you are missing..." not really, that's why I'm asking this question...
